# Docker build for numpy , pandas giving error

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile in a directory called docker_test. The structure of docker_test is as follows:

```
M00618927A:docker_test i854319$ ls 
Dockerfile  hello_world.py
```

My dockerfile looks like below:

```
  ### Dockerfile 

# Created by Baktaawar 

# Pulling from base Python image 

FROM python:3.6.7-alpine3.6

# author of file
LABEL maintainer="Baktawar"

# Set the working directory of the docker image 
WORKDIR /docker_test
COPY . /docker_test


# packages that we need

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install numpy pandas jupyter


EXPOSE 8888

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["hello_world.py"]
```

I run the command

```
docker build -t dockerfile .
```

It starts the building process but then gives the following error in not being able to get the numpy etc installed in the image

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/8 : FROM python:3.6.7-alpine3.6
 ---> 8f30079779ef
Step 2/8 : LABEL maintainer="Baktawar"
 ---> Running in 7cf081021b1e
Removing intermediate container 7cf081021b1e
 ---> 581cf24fa4e6
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /docker_test
 ---> Running in 7c58855c4332
Removing intermediate container 7c58855c4332
 ---> dae70a34626b
Step 4/8 : COPY . /docker_test
 ---> 432b174b4869
Step 5/8 : RUN pip --no-cache-dir install numpy pandas jupyter
 ---> Running in 972efa9336ed
Collecting numpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/8d/6345b4f32b37945fedc1e027e83970005fc9c699068d2f566b82826515f2/numpy-1.16.2.zip (5.1MB)
Collecting pandas
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/fd/b1f17f7dc914047cd1df9d6813b944ee446973baafe8106e4458bfb68884/pandas-0.24.1.tar.gz (11.8MB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
        module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]
    KeyError: 'numpy'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-8c3o0ycd/pandas/setup.py", line 732, in <module>
        ext_modules=maybe_cythonize(extensions, compiler_directives=directives),
      File "/tmp/pip-install-8c3o0ycd/pandas/setup.py", line 475, in maybe_cythonize
        numpy_incl = pkg_resources.resource_filename('numpy', 'core/include')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1142, in resource_filename
        return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_filename(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 359, in get_provider
        __import__(moduleOrReq)
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-8c3o0ycd/pandas/
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip --no-cache-dir install numpy pandas jupyter' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How can I get this basic setup done?

Comment: This may be different from your issue, but I've had problems with `numpy` and musl (alpine) in the past. You might want to try a glibc base image (e.g. `python:3.6-slim`) if that's within your constraints.

Comment: Let me try it and see

Comment: Is `alpine` absolutely needed? I had an experience in past trying to combine `alpine` with `pandas`/`numpy` and the size of final image was not less than non-`alpine`.

Comment: I don't know. I felt alpine is a smaller version of python. Is it advisable to use pre built base images for ubuntu or python or installing our own python is advisable?

Comment: I don't post it as answer but this docker was useful for me year ago: [pandas/Dockerfile](https://github.com/amancevice/pandas/blob/master/alpine/Dockerfile). You can see similarities with @andreas-lorenzen answer in `apk` commands

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You basically need to install the following on alpine, in order to be able to install numpy:

```
apk --no-cache add musl-dev linux-headers g++
```

Try the following Dockerfile:

```
### Dockerfile
# Created by Baktawar
# Pulling from base Python image

FROM python:3.6.7-alpine3.6

# author of file
LABEL maintainer="Baktawar"

# Set the working directory of the docker image
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Install native libraries, required for numpy
RUN apk --no-cache add musl-dev linux-headers g++

# Upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# packages that we need
RUN pip install numpy && \
    pip install pandas && \
    pip install jupyter

EXPOSE 8888

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["hello_world.py"]
```

You may find this gist interresting:

https://gist.github.com/orenitamar/f29fb15db3b0d13178c1c4dd611adce2

And this package on alpine, is also of interrest I think:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/py-numpy

**Update**

In order to tag the image properly, use the syntax:

```
docker build -f <dockerfile> -t <tagname:tagversion> <buildcontext>
```

For you, this would be:

```
docker build -t mypythonimage:0.1 .
```

Comment: Cool. I saw the other comment and it's an alpine issue. You have helped answer how to work with alpine. Gr8. One last question- my dockerfile is named dockerfile. How do I add tag to it. By default it adds latest tag. But I am not able to save the dockerfile txt file as dockerfile:test or something. It doesn't take : in file name while saving.

Comment: @Baktaawar it's not that "alpine has issues" - it's more about: after you `apk` all needed packages final image is not so thin.

Comment: Thanks - please mark the solution as accepted if it solves your issue :) otherwise, let me know what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with alpine. I replaced

> FROM python:3.9-alpine

with  `FROM python:3.9-slim-buster` . And it worked.

Ref;
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-dockerize-a-flask-app/

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use **Slim** images instead of other images, It worked for me.